# Properly configure .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

On localhost I have a file filename.html and an .htaccess in the same folder.

I need to figure out why my .htaccess is not working:

```
redirect 301 /filename.html http://www.google.com
```

I am on linux, I have configured the server:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">

                AllowOverride All
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I found:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^test\.html http://www.google.com/? [R=301,L]
```

my RewriteEngine is working.